# Ruby on Rails - how require is executed in application.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, require

I am reading a book for "Ruby on Rails". In the "application.js", we are including other JavaScript libraries in the following way and more specific - jQuery UI:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

As this is ordinary JavaScript file (not ruby extensions here like "html.erb" for exmaple) how the application knows to execute the require command? What kind of JavaScript syntax is this:

```
//=
```

and as this is ordinary JavaScript file, why we are not using "script" tags to include JavaScript files?

Also, I have read [here](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/require.htm) that "require" method will check for this library in define by $LOAD_PATH  variable folders. How can I see where the "jquery-ui" is stored? I am asking because in other applications in order to use jQuery UI I should add not only JavaScript file, but css file and images used by the library - in this case, we are doing this only with single line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### What kind of JavaScript syntax is this.

Anything starting with a `//` is a Javascript comment.

#### How is it able to process it ?

Sprockets on the server side scans the JS file for `directives`. `//=` is a special Sprocket directive. When it encounters that directive it asks the [Directive Processor](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#the-directive-processor) to process the command, `require` in this example. In the absence of Sprockets the `//= require ..` line would be a simple JS comment.

#### Ruby `require` vs Sprockets `require`

These are two completely different things. The one you link to is Ruby's require.

#### Why not use script tags to load JS files.

Usually, you want to concatenate all your app JS files and then minify them into 1 master JS file and then include that. I recommend reading the YSlow best practices on this.

I also recommend watching the Railscasts on Asset Pipline - http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

Cheers!